# Unicode Normalization

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, mojibake

Is there a possible normalization path which brings both strings below to same value?

- `u'Aho\xe2\u20ac\u201cCorasick_string_matching_algorithm'`
- `u'Aho\u2013Corasick string matching algorithm'`

Comment: I understand there have been lots of posts written on unicode handling.
More specifically related to above example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971634/is-django-double-encoding-a-unicode-utf-8-string 
but it relates to some MYSQL loading and its settings

Comment: Can you explain what a "normalization" path is?

Comment: Why would those two strings be equal *at all*? One uses `â€“` the other has an en-dash. Are you talking about repairing a Mojibake instead?

Comment: Not to mention the underscores-to-spaces.

Comment: U+2013 is an en-dash, U+20AB is the Euro sign. there is no Unicode normalisation that will change either (no combining characters involved). Are you confusing encoding with code points?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes I am talking of Mojibake. didn't know about this term before but just read about it after you mentioned.

Comment: @comiventor: then normalisation is not the right term; you are repairing (the value is broken).

Comment: @Richard: it is an encoding issue, yes. The 3 characters together are all Windows-1252 encodable, together forming the exact 3 bytes that UTF-8 encoding the en-dash would produce....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) there, UTF-8 bytes that have been decoded as if they were Windows-1252 data instead. Your 3 'characters', encoded to Windows-1252, produce the exact 3 UTF-8 bytes for the U+2013 EN DASH character in your target string:

```
>>> u'\u2013'.encode('utf8')
'\xe2\x80\x93'
>>> u'\u2013'.encode('utf8').decode('windows-1252')
u'\xe2\u20ac\u201c'
```

You can use the [`ftfy` module](http://ftfy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to repair that data, so you get an emdash for the bytes:

```
>>> import ftfy
>>> sample = u'Aho\xe2\u20ac\u201cCorasick_string_matching_algorithm'
>>> ftfy.fix_text(sample)
u'Aho\u2013Corasick_string_matching_algorithm'
```

then simply replace underscores with spaces:

```
>>> ftfy.fix_text(sample).replace('_', ' ')
u'Aho\u2013Corasick string matching algorithm'
```

You can also simply encode to Windows-1252 and decode again as UTF-8, but that doesn't *always* work because there are specific bytes that cannot be decoded legally as Windows-1252, but some systems producing these Mojibakes do so anyway. `ftfy` includes specialised repair codecs to reverse that process. In addition, it detects the specific Mojibake errors made to automate the process across multiple possible codec errors.